# jquery get the second value of input

Tags: php, jquery, insert

I have this jQuery code, when i click the first value of the Select it insert to the database, But when i click the second value of the Select, it insert again THE FIRST value of the Select. How can i insert the 2nd value of the select.
the sample link is : http://cocopop12.site11.com/search/index.php

the jQuery code of mine is :

```
$(function() {
    $(".videoThumbS").click(function() {
        var dataString = $("#v_w_id_value").val();
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST',                                  
            url: 'api.php',
            data: { v_w_id: dataString },
            dataType: 'html',               
            success: function(data)  
            {
            var v_w_id_value = data[0];           //get name
            $('#selected_thumbs').html("yt id:" + v_w_id_value );     //Set output element html
            } 
        });    
    });
});
```

my forms with foreach value.

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input id="v_w_id_value" type="hidden" name="v_w_id" value="OIUIUNKLJ" />
<input class="videoThumbS" type="button" name="selectSel" value="Select" id="selectbut" />
</form>
```

the value in the hidden i just insert it for example but it was loop to diff. value.

then it will insert to the database.

```
<?php
include ( 'class/conn.php' );
$v_watch_id = $_POST['v_w_id'];
$selected_videos = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO s_vids VALUE('', '$v_watch_id', NOW() )" ) or die ( mysql_error() );
?>
```

Inserting to the database was working but only the first value that was inserted, so when i click the second or third Select button it doesn't read the jQuery.
how can i fix it?

Using the firebug on firefox console javascript i can see the different value of select button.

Comment: where is your select element..?

Comment: You are using the same ID (and name) multiple times. The selector is going to find the first instance of it. That's all.

Comment: value of v_w_id_value is Kdo66I9gMwI for every time you click the select so that first record is only added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your explanation a little confusing, but I *think* you are saying you have repeated that form and its two input elements several times on the page, and when a particular "Select" button is clicked you want to submit its associated hidden value.

If so, try this minor change to your function:

```
var dataString = $(this).siblings('input[name="v_w_id"]').val();
```

Within your click handler `this` is the clicked element, so `$(this).siblings()` gets the siblings of the clicked element and using the selector `'input[name="v_w_id"]'` gets that particular sibling.

The way you were doing it you were selecting the hidden input with id `v_w_id_value`, which meant it would always select the same one. The id attribute is supposed to be unique, that is, no two elements should have the same id - if you break this rule the browser usually displays the page OK anyway, but your JS won't work properly: for most browsers selecting by the duplicated id will return the first element with that id.

Comment: OH MY GOD!!! it works :) thank you so much... now i know what .siblings is. thank you thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. As implied by my last paragraph, you should update your code to avoid repeating ids. In this case neither input in the form actually needs an id so I'd just remove the attribute completely.

Answer (score 0):

That is because once your success function is ran your program gets an error because data[0] is undefined.To fix try this in php file

```
<?php
include ( 'class/conn.php' );
$v_watch_id = $_POST['v_w_id'];
$selected_videos = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO s_vids VALUE('', '$v_watch_id', NOW() )" ) or die ( mysql_error() );
echo '["'.$v_watch_id.'"]';
?>
```